# OpenLayers. Marker info too big

Tags: openlayers

I have this piece of code to show a marker in a map, i am using openlayers ( an opensource javascript library to load, display and render maps from multiple sources on web pages), but the popup is too big

```
 <div class="windowContentMap">
                    <div>
                       <div id="Map"></div>
                         <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            var lat            = '50.8340150';
                            var lon            = '4.3778850';
                            var zoom           = 18;

                            var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
                            var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                            var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);

                            map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map");
                            var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
                            map.addLayer(mapnik);

                            var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
                            map.addLayer(markers);
                            markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));
                            map.setCenter(position, zoom);
                            // The location of our marker and popup. We usually think in geographic
                            // coordinates ('EPSG:4326'), but the map is projected ('EPSG:3857').
                            var myLocation = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon, lat).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

                            // A popup with some information about our location
                            var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("Popup",
                            myLocation.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(), null,
                            //'<a target="_blank" href="http://openlayers.org/">We</a> ' +
                            'E506  (TD1204 EVB)', null,
                            true // <-- true if we want a close (X) button, false otherwise
                        );
                        map.addPopup(popup);
                        </script>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use element id or override `olPopup` css class to set style of your popup:

```
var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("yourPopup",
        yourLonLat,
        null,
        htmlCode, //for example a table
        null,
        true,
        function () {
            //close popup function
        }
    );
```

And in your css file write something like:

```
#yourPopup {
    width: 100px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    /*set any style*/
}
```

Or:

```
.olPopup {
    /*set any style*/
}
```